# Firefox 4 and ASyncFileUpload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a [ASyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx) control placed in a hidden panel in an ASP.NET page. The panel is displayed when the user chooses a certain action, i.e. to provide some data via FileUpload.
There are a series of panels on the page whose visibility is toggled based on user input, pretty standard stuff. The panels themselves are contained within an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx), which has an associated [UpdateProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx)

When users click a button on my page that toggles the visibility of different panels, FireFox 4 does not hide the UpdateProgress.

Chrome does, IE 7,8,9 do. Firefox 3.6* did, however FireFox 4 refuses to hide the update progress.

As a result, the correct panel itself shows itself, but the UpdateProgress indicator refuses to hide itself after the appropriate panel is shown.

Firebug simply states:
*Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount"  code: "1*

pointing to an underlying file within the toolkit [itself](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/). I'm perplexed because its just FireFox 4 that is having issues, like I said Chrome and IE do not have this issue.

**UPDATE**: In case comments are not read: **This issue was fixed with the May 2011 release of the toolkit**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had something similar to this, and I found this [page](http://sry-for-my-english.blogspot.com/2011/03/ajaxcontroltoolkit-vs-ff4.html) to be somewhat helpful.

There will be an updated/fixed binary you'll have to use. It can be found on that website, or you can compile your own using the fixes that the post indicates.

The fixes:

> try/catching the suspicious block (line 187) in AsyncFileUpload.pre.js

and

> removing redundant id attribute of the HTMLInputFile in AsyncFileUpload.cs in the OnPreRender method.

Comment: Thanks, Will give this a try, I searched a lot but never hit this person's site

Comment: Also in case anyone was wondering, this issue was fixed with the May 2011 release of the toolkit as well

Comment: Np, your fix worked, then I open an issue on Codeplex, and they had fixed it. :)

Comment: Oh nice! Got to the root of the problem!